# how do i make the correct use of toString method in my following code?

Tags: java, tostring

i wanted to print an assigned value using the `tostring()` method in the following way in my program :

```
class employee
{
    double b;
}
class manager extends employee
{
}
public class employeestockplan
{
    static Object o;
    public void agrantstock()
    {
        if(o instanceof manager)
        {
            ((employee) o).b = 80000;
        }
        else if(o instanceof employee)
        {
            ((employee) o).b  = 50000;
        }
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return ((employee) o).b+" ";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        o = new employee();
        employeestockplan t = new employeestockplan();
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

But the output is `0.0`, where should i modify my program ? i personally think i have erred in specifying if o is an object of employee or manager else misplacing the `toString` method, but then i am not sure.

Comment: Use the proper name - `toString()`

Comment: oops my mistake, but then too it gives another unwanted output....that's 0.0

Comment: You're not calling `agrantstock()` anywhere so the value of `b` in your `employee` object is still `0.0`. Call `agrantstock()` before you print `t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the method `toString` in the class `employeestockplan`, and here you misspelled it, it is not `tostring` but `toString`. Yes Java is case sensitive.

**Response update:**

You never call `agrantstock()` in your current code that is why you get 0. Try this:

```
employeestockplan.o = new employee();
employeestockplan t = new employeestockplan();
t.agrantstock();
System.out.println(t);
```

**Output:**

```
50000.0
```

**NB:** `o` should be of type `employee` instead of `Object`, it would simplify  your code a lot and you should implement a method `agrantstock` in `employee` and override it in `manager` this way you won't need to test the type with instanceof anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you never call the *agrantstock()* method that assigns the value to *b*.

You can simplify that method by making your static property an *Employee* instead of an *Object*.  Here is a slightly reworked version of your code, also modified to follow standard naming conventions:

```
class Employee {
    double b;
}

class Manager extends Employee {
}

public class EmployeeStockPlan {

    static Employee employee;

    public void grantStock() {
        if (employee instanceof Manager) {
            employee.b = 80000;
        } else {
            employee.b = 50000;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ((Employee) employee).b + " ";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        employee = new Employee();
        EmployeeStockPlan stockPlan = new EmployeeStockPlan();
        stockPlan.grantStock();
        System.out.println(stockPlan);
    }
}
```

Note the addition of ***stockPlan.grantStock()*** in the main method.